# php looping through multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have a form that has 7 different criteria.  Each criteria has 3 or 4 questions that a user will check the appropriate value.

I want to loop through each question and create a string which contains the criteria id -> question id -> and answer value.

I cannot seem to get it to work.

Here is a dump of the arrays:

**criteria array:**

```
array(7) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "3" [2]=> string(1) "5" [3]=> string(1) "7" [4]=> string(2) "10" [5]=> string(2) "11" [6]=> string(2) "12" }
```

**criteria id associated with each question**

```
array(19) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(1) "1" [3]=> string(1) "3" [4]=> string(1) "3" [5]=> string(1) "3" [6]=> string(1) "5" [7]=> string(1) "5" [8]=> string(1) "5" [9]=> string(1) "7" [10]=> string(1) "7" [11]=> string(1) "7" [12]=> string(1) "7" [13]=> string(2) "10" [14]=> string(2) "10" [15]=> string(2) "10" [16]=> string(2) "11" [17]=> string(2) "11" [18]=> string(2) "11" }
```

**Question and answer array(only answered 6 question)**

```
array(6) { [11]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "5" } [12]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "5" } [13]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "5" } [14]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "4" } [15]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "4" } [16]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "4" } }
```

Here is my code for looping that doesn't seem to work:

```
                  $criteriaNums = $_POST['criteriaNum'];
              $fk_criterias = $_POST['fk_criteria'];
              $questionValue = $_POST['questionValue'];

              foreach($questionValue as $question => $answer){
                //echo $question;
                    foreach($fk_criterias as $fk){
                        foreach($criteriaNums as $crit){
                            if($fk == $crit){
                                $string1 = $fk;
                                //echo $string1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    $string2 = $question;
                    foreach ( $answer as $result ){
                      $string3 = $result;
                      //echo $string3;
                  }
                $criteria .= $string1 . '|' . $string2 . '|' . $string3 . '|';
                //echo $criteria;
              }
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Strings 2 and 3 seem to be working fine.  It is string1 that isn't working.

this is the output the above code generates:

11|11|5|11|11|5|11|12|5|11|11|5|11|12|5|11|13|5|11|11|5|11|12|5|11|13|5|11|14|4|11|11|5|11|12|5|11|13|5|11|14|4|11|15|4|11|11|5|11|12|5|11|13|5|11|14|4|11|15|4|11|16|4|

This is how this should work:

There is a total of 19 questions.  In the above question/answer array dump the user only answered 6.

The first question is id #11 and the answer is value 5.
the second question is id #12 and the answer is value 5 
third is id #13 answer is 5
4th is id #14 answer is 4
5th is id #15 answer is 4
6th is id #16 answer is 4

The criteria id array dump above is the associated criteria that goes with each question.  if you look at the dump you can see the first 6 (0 - 5) has 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3

so the expected output should be

1 | 11 | 5 |
1 | 12 | 5 |
1 | 13 | 5 |
3 | 14 | 4 |
3 | 15 | 4 |
3 | 16 | 4 |

I hope this helps?

Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [11] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5
                )

```
        [12] => Array
            (
                [0] => 5
            )

        [13] => Array
            (
                [0] => 5
            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [14] => Array
            (
                [0] => 5
            )

        [15] => Array
            (
                [0] => 5
            )

        [16] => Array
            (
                [0] => 5
            )

    )
```

)

1|11|5|1|12|5|1|13|5|3|14|5|3|15|5|3|16|5|

Here is my code:

```
                foreach ($questionValue as $crit => $questions) {
                    foreach ($questions as $answer => $result) {
                        foreach($result as $value){
                            $criteria = $crit . "|" . $answer . "|" . $value . "|";
                            echo $criteria;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide output? Can you please provide an example of the input arrays? The part doing `$string1` looks ok, without the aforementioned data it is doubful that the problem can be resolved.

This one looks strange:

```
foreach ( $answer as $result ){
                      $string3 = $result;
                      //echo $string3;
                  }
```

You may either want to add a condition (like in criteria) or do `$string3 .= $result;`

Comment: I have added the output to the original question

Comment: can you please provide input data too? (+maybe a hand-crafted expected output for the input)

Comment: I have added the input

Comment: I'm not yet sure, what is that criteria is for? Anyway, I think that it would be better to turn fk_criterias and criteriaNums into a single associative array (where keys are Questions IDs and values are arrays of criteria nums).

Comment: I am getting close.  I made the $_POST a 3 dimensional array and included the criteria id.  I added my array dump and output.  The only issue now is that it echos fine inside the nested loop.  It only echos the last value outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue:

I used concatenation for the values.

Here is my code:

```
                foreach ($questionValue as $crit => $questions) {
                    foreach ($questions as $answer => $result) {
                        foreach($result as $value){
                            $string .= $crit . "|" . $answer . "|" . $value . "|";
                            //echo $criteria;
                        }
                    }
                  $criteria = $string;
                }
```